# Creating lines between points in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, point

I have a 44 points which are extracted from a survey line. I want to calculate the average distance between the points, so I thought it would be an idea to create lines between the points and then calculate the average length of these.

They are not grouped, but have a timestamp and coordinates.

Is it possible to somehow create lines between the points without grouping them?

Comment: Does [this](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012092) help?

Comment: You can calculate distance between points many, many ways, most easier than by constructing lines. If the coordinate reference is projected, you can even just take the square root of the sum of squares.